# High CPU usage on powerful laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, cpu-load

I have a relatively powerful laptop:

```
-Computer-
Processor        : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory           : 32859MB (2612MB used)
Operating System : Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
-Display-
Resolution       : 3840x1600 pixels
OpenGL Renderer  : Quadro M2000M/PCIe/SSE2
X11 Vendor       : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter    : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
Audio Adapter    : HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
```

I have to use `Ubuntu 16 LTS` on it.
My issue is that when I open a window and just move it around slightly the CPU usage by `xorg` jumps to almost 100%.

At first I thought that the build-in graphic card was being used and that was making the CPU work harder, but the output from the following shows that the NVIDIA card is indeed being used.

```
~$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro M2000M/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_KHR_robustness, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_KHR_robustness, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
    GL_EXT_protected_textures, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness,
```

I am using the proprietary `Nvidia Driver 384.111`, which is relativly new.

Any ideas why my CPU is so jumpy when moving a window (or even tabbing between different windows)?

Comment: Do things improve after `prime-select intel` (switch to iGPU) followed by `reboot`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, why would that help? Best case scenario it would switch to the weaker graphic card. Or am I missing something?

Comment: On my own system the Gtx 970M makes system 20 C hotter and windows lag moving them.